# ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3, scrollview

I have a flutter app based on Google map, in this app there is bottom list for locations, and also markers to show the locations in the map, and when i click on the marker directly show the specific list item, and vise versa that mean also when click on list item show me the marker related with this location.

every thing works good, but when I use Navigator to go to this page for map show me this error:

Note :  i am wondering what is the different between lunching my app in this screen and go to it by using Navigator, because in the first scenario it is work, and with navigator it shows this problem
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building AnimatedBuilder(animation: PageController#8776c(2 clients), dirty, state: _AnimatedState#3f7db):
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 113 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///H:/mafqood/lib/ui/widgets/places_bottom_list_widget.dart:79:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      ScrollController.position (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:113:12)
#3      PlacesListState.tile.<anonymous closure> (package:mafqood/ui/widgets/places_bottom_list_widget.dart:83:28)
#4      AnimatedBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/transitions.dart:1443:19)
#5      _AnimatedState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/transitions.dart:181:48)
#6      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 113 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedBuilder file:///H:/mafqood/lib/ui/widgets/places_bottom_list_widget.dart:79:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

id define PageControler in the seperate file called (config.dart):

```
 PageController pageController;
```

and then use it here in another file:

```
class PlacesListState extends State<PlacesList> {
  GetPlacesBloc getPlacesBloc;
  double offset = 0.0 ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 1, viewportFraction: 0.8)..addListener(() {
      setState(() {
          offset = PageController().offset;
      });
    });

    getPlacesBloc = BlocProvider.of<GetPlacesBloc>(context);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    getPlacesBloc.close();
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Positioned(
      bottom: 36.0,
      child: Container(
          height: 150.0,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: BlocBuilder<GetPlacesBloc, GetPlacesStates>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is GetPlacesLoadingState) {
                return LoadingIndicator(
                  message: state.message,
                );
              } else if (state is GetPlacesSuccessState) {
                return PageView.builder(
                  controller: pageController,
                  itemCount: state != null ? state.places.length : 0,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return tile(context, state.places[index], index);
                  },
                );
              } else if (state is GetPlacesErrorState) {
                return Text(state.message);
              } else {
                return Container(
                  width: 0,
                  height: 0,
                );
              }
            },
          )),
    );
  }

  tile(BuildContext context, PlaceModel place, int index) {

    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: pageController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
        double value = 1;
        if (pageController.position.haveDimensions) {
          value = pageController.page - index;
          value = (1 - (value.abs() * 0.3) + 0.06).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
        }
```

and here in with markers:

```
void tileScrollTo(int i) {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      i,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
    );
  }
  /////////////

   getAllMarkers(List<PlaceModel> places) {
    for(int i =0; i < places.length; i++) {
      markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('${places[i].pid}'),
          position: LatLng(double.parse(places[i].lat), double.parse(places[i].lon)),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueAzure),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: '${places[i].title}', snippet: '${places[i].details}'),
           onTap: () => tileScrollTo(i),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems from the code you are reusing the same PageController in two places, once in PageView.builder and second time in tileScrollTo? You may use a separate controller for tileScrollTo.

Comment: yes right, but if using a separate controller, it will not work, because one connected with another, when i click on list item navigate me to marker with location and vise versa, so how can i do that with separate controller?

Comment: Do you wish to sync the positions of the two? In that case it is best to use NotificationListener widget and sync the positions in onNotification callback of the NotificationListener.

Comment: no, actually it is work good, except when i use Navigator in order to access this screen? i am wondering what is the different between lunching my app in this screen and go to it by using Navigator, because in the first scenario it is work, and with navigator it shows this problem !!!